# Rx and Declaration or statement expected

Tags: angular

Below is my code using RC1:

```
    ngOnInit(){
    var id = this._routeParams.get("id");

    this.title = id ? "Edit User" : "New User";

    if (!id)
        return;

    this._slugService.getSlug(id)
        .subscribe(
            slug => this.slug = slug,
            response => {
                if (response.status == 404) {
                    this._router.navigate(['NotFound']);
                }
            });
}




onSubmit(){
        this.dd = 'YAY';
        //console.log('adfasdf');

        /*
        this._slugService.addSlug(this.form.value)
            .subscribe(x => {
                // Ideally, here we'd want:
                // this.form.markAsPristine();
                    this._router.navigate(['Slugs']);
            });
        */ 

        var result:any;

        if (this.slug.id) 
            result = this._slugService.updateSlug(this.slug);
        else
            result = this._slugService.addSlug(this.slug)

            /*PROBLEM IS HERE!!!!*/
            result.subscribe(x => {

                this._router.navigate(['Slugs']);
            });

    }
```

for the variable x I get the below

```
Parameter 'x' implicitly has 'any' type




app/slugs/slug-form.component.ts(98,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.2.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

If I comment out the code my application starts.  How do I fix?

Below is the returned "result" from the console:

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}_isScalar: falseoperator: MapOperatorproject: (res)arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 1name: ""prototype: Object__proto__: ()<function scope>thisArg: undefined__proto__: Objectcall: (subscriber, source)constructor: MapOperator(project, thisArg)__proto__: Objectsource: Observable_isScalar: false_subscribe: (responseObserver)__proto__: Object__proto__: Object_subscribe: (subscriber)constructor: Observable(subscribe)forEach: (next, PromiseCtor)lift: (operator)map: map(project, thisArg)subscribe: (observerOrNext, error, complete)Symbol(Symbol.observable): ()__proto__: Object
```

In chrome when I go to the subscriber I see this error:

```
[Exception: TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context. at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:3:14) at Object.InjectedScript.callFunctionOn (<anonymous>:124:124)]
caller
:
(...)
length
:
1
name
:
""
prototype
:
Object
__proto__
:
()
<function scope>
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
_subscribe
:
(subscriber)
constructor
:
Observable(subscribe)
forEach
:
(next, PromiseCtor)
lift
:
(operator)
map
:
map(project, thisArg)
subscribe
:
(observerOrNext, error, complete)
Symbol(Symbol.observable)
:
()
__proto__
:
Object
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `tsconfig.json` add:

```
{
...
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "noImplicitAny": false
        ...
    }
...
}
```

That will fix the problem with `x` variable.